# React, cannot reset checkbox to default unchecked state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I'm trying reproduce Youtuber Traversy Media's [React JS crash course 2021](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7ejDZ8SWv8&t=4707s) Task Tracker project with Reactstrap, and using the same method (a component level hook) to create a form with a checkbox in it, and I set up a method, make sure after the form submitted, the text area will be set to empty and the checkbox set to false, and therefore unchecked. When I hit submit, the checkbox had set to false, but remain checked.

[image: ,]

From the React dev tool, the value is reset to false and the checkbox should be unchecked, I don't know what went wrong, I did the exact same thing as the video did. I have problem pasting code here, so left out non-related part, like the input text code. Thanks in advance!

```
const [reminder, setReminder] = useState(false);
const onSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault()

if (!text) {
  alert('Please add a task')
  return
}

onAdd({ text, day, reminder })

setText('')
setDay('')
setReminder(false)}

      {/* checkbox here */}
  <div className="mb-3 form-check">
    <input
      type="checkbox"
      id="checkbox1"
      className="form-check-input"
      value={reminder}
      onChange={(e) => setReminder(e.currentTarget.checked)}
    />
    <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="checkbox1">
      Set reminder
    </label>
  </div>

  {/* submit button */}
  <div className="d-grid">
    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing as below  would work. Notice I'm using `checked` and not `value` as you did, the reason why it's not working for you.

```
const [reminder, setReminder] = useState(false);
```

```js
<input
  type="checkbox"
  id="checkbox1"
  className="form-check-input"
  checked={reminder}
  onChange={(e) => setReminder(e.currentTarget.checked)}
/>
```

To know more about the difference between `value` and `checked`, you can visite this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#additional_attributes) from MDN.